# Making Column Records as Column Names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table :

```
 A | B
---+---
 a | 1qw
 b | 2q
 c | 3s
 a | 4sd
 b | 5 
 c | 6
```

Output Table:

```
 a | b | c 
---+---+---
1qw| 2q| 3s 
4sd| 5 | 6
```

How can i get the output table in sql server. This is an example and there could be more than 3 distinct records in the first column.

I used :

```
select a,b,c from 
(select A,B from TABLE) as P
Pivot (max(B) for A in (a,b,c)
```

This only gives me 1 of the rows (which is not even correct).

Comment: Research `PIVOT`

Comment: I guess this is going to receive at least 2x downvotes, it's better to add some effort or delete this question as soon as possible, otherwise that is almost coming true.

Comment: I don't know why this is being voted to close as *Unclear what you are asking*?  It is very clear what is being asked, this is just a very low effort question.

Comment: @Alex could you please give me a code snippet/ link. I looked at pivot and unfortunately i couldn't understand.

Comment: @KingKing Kindly explain to me, how can i add more effort to explain something that I feel is explained perfectly.

Comment: @iamdave i dont think it is low effort. Its a simple question, but i am pretty sure the solution isnt very easy.

Comment: The solution is *very* easy, you just haven't looked very hard for it.  As Alex said, look up the `pivot` statement and try something.  If you get stuck, add what you have tried to your question and we will help you from there.

Comment: @iamdave alright, thanks!

Comment: @iamdave please have a look!!

Comment: @Alex Can you have a look as well?

Comment: @TheNoob The query behave correctly.  When you PIVOT the MAX(B), you'll get 1 row.

Comment: @TheNoob the problem is not explanation, it's totally clear what your problem is. The effort here is what you've  tried so far, at least by searching through Google first, you should find some beginning point to start writing your own query, even a copied one is fine, it's even acceptable that when you know about PIVOT using in some simple example but in this specific case you don't know how to apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quickest for you and easiest for us to answer these types of questions, when you provide a fully working valid SQL code example (even if does not get what you want) with DDL scripts like below:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data( ID INT IDENTITY, A1 CHAR( 1 ), B1 VARCHAR( 5 ))
INSERT INTO #Data
VALUES
( 'a', '1qw' ), ( 'b', '2q ' ), ( 'c', '3s ' ),
( 'a', '4sd' ), ( 'b', '5  ' ), ( 'c', '6  ' )
```

The trick is to have a "Group ID" column that identifies groups ("buckets") of a, b, c records:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY A1 ORDER BY ID ) AS GroupID
FROM #Data
ORDER BY GroupID
```

I assumed that you have "positional dependency" on ID column and that your groups are derived from the value of ID column i.e. b record with ID = 2 is in the same group as preceding a record with ID = 1. If your initial data setup is different then you need to come up with your own logic of how to assign "Group ID"s.

The final PIVOT query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
( SELECT A1, B1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY A1 ORDER BY ID ) AS GroupID
FROM #Data ) AS data
PIVOT(
    MAX( B1 ) FOR A1 IN( [a], [b], [c] )
) AS P
```

Output:

```
GroupID              a     b     c
-------------------- ----- ----- -----
1                    1qw   2q    3s 
2                    4sd   5     6
```

References: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot